# GCP iot Core to pubsub messages not showing up

Tags: google-cloud-iot

I am trying to integrate GCP with loraserver using LorixOne Gateway, I am following the guide at https://www.loraserver.io/guides/google-cloud-platform/
However my messages not reaching to loraserver through pubsub.

My setup is as below:
lora end device—>LorixOne Gateway with Lora base OS —> GCP IoT core -> GCP Pubsub —> VM running loraserver

I can see that all messages are reaching to IoT core but nothing can be seen on the pubsub or lora-app-server.

I am following the guide https://www.loraserver.io/guides/google-cloud-platform/   however something is not working ok with GCP PUBSUB[Here is picture from GCP logs that I am getting messages to IOT core however nothing reaches to VM via pubsub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdnDP.png)

Answer (score 0):

So issue here was not from Google cloud iot.  there were 2 issues here.

1) gateway id is case sensitive
2) end lorwan device was not transmitting on right AU_915 band

Now all looks good.

Regards
Jayesh